Ensuring each table's column dropdown filter can filter all other column dropdown filters without unwanted interactions
Is there a simple 'filter all other dropdowns according to the one that triggered the 'change' event?
My goal: Build an excel-style 'Autofilter' dropdown for each column in a table. Filter each column's dropdown options by those selected in the other columns.
The table has 3 columns: Category, Subcategory, Product.
I'm struggling to find a simple way to script 'Filter all other dropdowns by this dropdown', other than specifically mapping Column 1's filter conditions to Columns 2 and 3, and likewise mapping Column 2's filters to Columns 1 and 3 etc. This would have clear scaling issues.
The current approach overview is below (Note how it currently cascades from category => subcategory => product, but I aim to have all dropdowns being able to filter each other)

Webpage loads =>

populatedropdown() adds event listeners to all checkboxes =>

EVENT: a checkbox 'check' value is changed =>


4a) call filtersubcategories() to modify available subcategory dropdown options according to category dropdown selections
AND
4b) call filterproducts() to do the same with available product dropdown options
(Disclaimer: yes, I've googled around and whilst there's loads of advice about dropdown filters in JS (using react, for example), 1) it tends to be 'directional' (i.e., 'cascade filters so column 1 filters column 2 but not vice versa). I can't find anything relating to ensuring that the filtering in one dropdown filters all other available options in the table-if there's any available materials/libraries to help, I'm all ears!)
I considered pasting the filterSubcategories() and filterProducts() (plus relevant event listeners) as snippets, but I figured there the rest of the script could be useful for
context.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Data Table with Filtering</title>
<style>
    /* Style for the table */
    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
    }
    th, td {
        border: 1px solid #dddddd;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 8px;
    }
    tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
    }
    .filter-dropdown {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .filter-dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        min-width: 150px;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        z-index: 1;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    .filter-dropdown-content label {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Data Table with Filtering</h2>
<div>
    <input type="text" id="categoryInput" onkeyup="filterTable()" placeholder="Filter by Category..">
    <input type="text" id="subcategoryInput" onkeyup="filterTable()" placeholder="Filter by Subcategory..">
    <input type="text" id="productInput" onkeyup="filterTable()" placeholder="Filter by Product..">
    <button onclick="resetFilters()">Reset Filters</button>
</div>

<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <div class="filter-dropdown" onclick="toggleDropdown('categoryDropdown')">Category ▼</div>
        <div class="filter-dropdown-content" id="categoryDropdown"></div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div class="filter-dropdown" onclick="toggleDropdown('subcategoryDropdown')">Subcategory ▼</div>
        <div class="filter-dropdown-content" id="subcategoryDropdown"></div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div class="filter-dropdown" onclick="toggleDropdown('productDropdown')">Product ▼</div>
        <div class="filter-dropdown-content" id="productDropdown"></div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>

<script>
var data = [
    { Category: "Category 1", Subcategory: "Subcategory 1", Product: "Product 1"},
    { Category: "Category 1", Subcategory: "Subcategory 2", Product: "Product 2"},
    { Category: "Category 2", Subcategory: "Subcategory 3", Product: "Product 3"},
    { Category: "Category 2", Subcategory: "Subcategory 1", Product: "Product 4"},
    { Category: "Category 2", Subcategory: "Subcategory 3", Product: "Product 5"},
];

// JavaScript for filtering the table
function filterTable() {
  var table, tbody, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
  var filters = Array.from(inputs).map(input => input.value.toUpperCase());
  var filterValues = {
    category: [],
    subcategory: [],
    product: []
  };
  checkboxes.forEach(function(checkbox) {
    if (checkbox.classList.contains('categoryFilter')) {
      filterValues.category.push(checkbox.value.toUpperCase());
    } else if (checkbox.classList.contains('subcategoryFilter')) {
      filterValues.subcategory.push(checkbox.value.toUpperCase());
    } else if (checkbox.classList.contains('productFilter')) {
      filterValues.product.push(checkbox.value.toUpperCase());
    }
  });
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
  tbody.innerHTML = ""; // Clear existing table body
  data.forEach(function(item) {
    if (
      (filters[0] === "" || item.Category.toUpperCase().includes(filters[0])) &&
      (filters[1] === "" || item.Subcategory.toUpperCase().includes(filters[1])) &&
      (filters[2] === "" || item.Product.toUpperCase().includes(filters[2])) &&
      (filterValues.category.length === 0 || filterValues.category.includes(item.Category.toUpperCase())) &&
      (filterValues.subcategory.length === 0 || filterValues.subcategory.includes(item.Subcategory.toUpperCase())) &&
      (filterValues.product.length === 0 || filterValues.product.includes(item.Product.toUpperCase()))
    ) {
      var row = document.createElement("tr");
      Object.values(item).forEach(function(value) {
        var cell = document.createElement("td");
        cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(value));
        row.appendChild(cell);
      });
      tbody.appendChild(row);
    }
  });
}

// JavaScript for resetting filters
function resetFilters() {
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');
  inputs.forEach(input => input.value = "");
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
  checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => checkbox.checked = false);
  filterTable(); // Reset the table to its initial state
}

// JavaScript for dropdown filters
function toggleDropdown(dropdownId) {
    var dropdown = document.getElementById(dropdownId);
    dropdown.style.display = (dropdown.style.display === 'block') ? 'none' : 'block';
}

// Function to get unique values from an array
function getUniqueValues(data, key) {
  return Array.from(new Set(data.map(item => item[key])));
}

// Populate table on page load
window.onload = function() {
  filterTable();
};

// Populate dropdown options
function populateDropdown(dropdownId, options) {
  var dropdownContent = document.getElementById(dropdownId);
  dropdownContent.innerHTML = "";
  options.forEach(function(option) {
    var label = document.createElement("label");
    var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
    checkbox.type = "checkbox";
    checkbox.value = option;
    checkbox.className = dropdownId === "categoryDropdown" ? "categoryFilter" :
                         dropdownId === "subcategoryDropdown" ? "subcategoryFilter" : "productFilter";
    checkbox.addEventListener("change", function() {
      filterTable();
      if (dropdownId === "categoryDropdown") {
        filterSubcategories();
        filterProducts();
      } else if (dropdownId === "subcategoryDropdown") {
        filterProducts();
      }
    });
    label.appendChild(checkbox);
    label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(option));
    dropdownContent.appendChild(label);
  });
}

// Populate dropdowns on page load
window.onload = function() {
  var categoryOptions = getUniqueValues(data, "Category").sort();
  var subcategoryOptions = getUniqueValues(data, "Subcategory").sort();
  var productOptions = getUniqueValues(data, "Product").sort();
  populateDropdown("categoryDropdown", categoryOptions);
  populateDropdown("subcategoryDropdown", subcategoryOptions);
  populateDropdown("productDropdown", productOptions);
  filterTable(); // Populate the table
};

// Filter subcategories based on selected categories
function filterSubcategories() {
  var categoryCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.categoryFilter:checked');
  var subcategoryCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.subcategoryFilter');
  subcategoryCheckboxes.forEach(function(checkbox) {
    // checkbox.disabled = true;
    checkbox.parentNode.style.display = "none";
  });
  categoryCheckboxes.forEach(function(checkbox) {
    var subcategoryOptions = data.filter(function(item) {
      return item.Category === checkbox.value;
    }).map(function(item) {
      return item.Subcategory;
    });
    subcategoryCheckboxes.forEach(function(subCheckbox) {
      if (subcategoryOptions.includes(subCheckbox.value)) {
        subCheckbox.parentNode.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        subCheckbox.parentNode.display = "none";
        subCheckbox.checked = false;
      }
    });
  });
}

// Filter products based on selected subcategories
function filterProducts() {
  var categoryCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.categoryFilter:checked');
  var subcategoryCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.subcategoryFilter:checked');
  var productCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.productFilter');
  productCheckboxes.forEach(function(checkbox) {
    checkbox.parentNode.style.display = "none";
    // checkbox.display = false
  });
  subcategoryCheckboxes.forEach(function(checkbox) {
    var productOptions = data.filter(function(item) {
      return item.Subcategory === checkbox.value;
    }).map(function(item) {
      return item.Product;
    });
    productCheckboxes.forEach(function(prodCheckbox) {
      if (productOptions.includes(prodCheckbox.value)) {
        prodCheckbox.parentNode.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        prodCheckbox.parentNode.style.display = "none";
        prodCheckbox.checked = false;
      }
    });
  });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>

